# Manual bootstrap with async service calls

Tags: angularjs

I have this problem where I need to authenticate the user before my app bootstraps. I've tried the following but the problem is that the modules $routeChangeStart events gets somehow fired before I manually call the bootstrap method.

```
window.onload = function (){

    var $rootElement, modules, $injector, $compile, compositeLinkFn, $rootScope, $localStorage, Security, SecurityRepository;

    // without this I'll get Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- $location <- $location
    $rootElement = angular.element(window.document.body);
    modules = [
        'ng',             // angular module
        'myapp.security', // the only module I need before bootstrapping
        function ($provide) { 
            $provide.value('$rootElement', $rootElement);
        }
    ];

    // one injector per application
    $injector = angular.injector(modules);

    // Compile Service: it traverses the DOM and look for directives and  compile and return linking function. No accecess to scope
    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');

    // Hold of the rootscope
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

    $localStorage = $injector.get('$localStorage');

    if ($localStorage.token) {
        Security = $injector.get('Security');
        SecurityRepository = $injector.get('SecurityRepository');
        refreshToken()
            .then(getUser)
            .then(setUser)
            .then(function (response) {
                // collection of all linking function. Here scope is getting accessed
                compositeLinkFn = $compile($rootElement);
                compositeLinkFn($rootScope);
                $rootScope.$apply();

                // If I do this, everything gets back to initial state
                // angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['parisrioApp']);
            });
    } else {
        // collection of all linking function. Here scope is getting accessed
        compositeLinkFn = $compile($rootElement);
        compositeLinkFn($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$apply();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function refreshToken() {
        var oldToken;

        oldToken = $localStorage.token;

        return SecurityRepository.refreshToken(oldToken.refreshToken)
            .then(refreshTokenComplete, refreshTokenFailed);

        function refreshTokenComplete(response) {
            $localStorage.token = response.data;
            return $localStorage.token;
        }

        function refreshTokenFailed(error) {
            delete $localStorage.token;
        }
    }

    function getUser() {
        return SecurityRepository.getUserInfo();
    }

    function setUser(response) {
        Security.changeUser(response.data);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get around this?

I've place the code above as the last script block (i.e. after angular and every app-related js-files). The version running is Angular 1.2.28

Comment: Which router are you using? If using ui-router it's very easy to set a parent abstract state and use a resolve to handle this

Comment: @charlietfl I'm using the default router. Anyhow, that suggestion is not an option because of current code base